# Wrong units displayed in data.table with POSIXct arithmetic

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

When durations are computed in data.table (v1.9.2), the wrong units can be printed with POSIXct arithmetic. It seems the first units are chosen.

```
require("data.table")
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2), 
                  event=rep(c("start", "end"), times=2), 
                  time=c(as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-31 06:05:30", 
                                      "2014-01-31 06:45:30", 
                                      "2014-01-31 08:10:00", 
                                      "2014-01-31 09:30:00"))))
dt$time[2] - dt$time[1]  # in minutes
dt$time[4] - dt$time[3]  # in hours
dt[ , max(time) - min(time), by=id]  # wrong units printed for id 2
```

I realize that one of these is the correct way to do it to get expected behavior, but wanted to report this behavior. Not sure if it is really a data.table problem or POSIXct problem.

```
dt[ , difftime(max(time), min(time), units="mins"), by=id]  # both in mins
dt[ , difftime(max(time), min(time), units="hours"), by=id]  # both in hours
```

Comment: Agreed it's a `data.table` problem with `POSIXct`. Thanks for filing the good report: [issue 761](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get the expected result if you do

```
dt[ , list(c(max(time) - min(time)),attr(max(time) - min(time),"units")), by=id]
```

Putting the `c()` around the time operation eliminates the attribute so you just get a number and then explicitly asking for the `"units"` attribute as another list element by itself gets the proper unit in its own column.  The reason it doesn't work without doing it this way is that `data.table` doesn't parse out attributes to be other columns and that is how POSIXct returns the units.

---

From Matt:

+1 Just to add a small speed improvement to save the `max(time)-min(time)` twice :

```
dt[ , list(c(d<-max(time) - min(time)), attr(d,"units")), by=id]
   id        V1    V2
1:  1 40.000000  mins
2:  2  1.333333 hours
```

At least to start with, I guess we'll add a check for inconsistent attributes across group results and then issue a warning/error. So this solution (or the one in the question) will likely be needed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This could be viewed as operator error, because your table is (automatically) displaying a numeric equivalent of a difftime, but you are not specifying which units to display the answer in. In most cases where you wish to export/display difftime values the desired units should be specified in an explicit conversion to numeric. E.g.

```
dt[ , as.numeric( max(time) - min(time), units="hours" ), by=id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing units is the way to go until [#761](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/761) is fixed. Here's another option:

```
dt[ , difftime(max(time), min(time), units = 'mins'), by = id]
#    id      V1
# 1:  1 40 mins
# 2:  2 80 mins
```

This allows you to retain the `class` of the output (`difftime`) if you'd like.

More than anything I find the behavior of R to fundamentally change the contents of the `difftime` object based on the `units` attribute quite strange. In other places in R, this conversion would simply be handled by the `print` method while the stored value of the object remains consistent.